# Read post response in AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, response, angular-resource

I'm consuming an post service using in AngularJs, that post returns a boolean value that I can see it in the Google Developer Tools, but I can't find a way to read it in the code, is there a way to read it?

Service.js

```
var impServices = angular.module('presupuestoServices', ['ngResource']);

impServices.factory('Cliente', ['$resource',
    function($resource){

    return  $resource( 'http://localhost:8080/IBascansService/AddCliente', {}, {
        addCliente: 
            {
            method:'POST', 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: {nombre_cliente: '@nombre_cliente'}
        }

    });
}]);
```

Controlers.js

```
var presupuestoControlers = angular.module('presupuestoControllers', []);

presupuestoControlers.controller('audClienteCtrl', ['$scope', 'Cliente',
    function($scope, Cliente){


    $scope.save = function(cli)
    {
        Cliente.addCliente({nombre_cliente: cli.nombre_cliente}, function(response){
            $scope.mes = response
        }); 
    }
}]);
```

An image of the Develpers Tools.

[image: DeveloperTools]

Thanks in advance, an Im open to any solution!

Comment: Capture the returned response in a var and return the var. Please a breakpoint on the return and you should be able to see what was assigned to the var from your response.

Comment: why wouldn't you send it in json and consume it the same way you do all other data?

Comment: also note that what you receive is a string...not a boolean so as string you need to convert...but it would. be boolean if parsed from json

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick anwsers, @Chris I already tried to save the data in a var, and I cant find the response.

Comment: I just wanted to keep simple my service, and just return a 'true' or 'false', but it seems that is not very simple to see the post response @charlietfl

Comment: `body` isn't part of the `$resource` action config spec. You also don't need the header you're setting; `application/json` is the default content type. Can you explain what the problem is? I don't really see anything wrong with your code

Comment: Thanks for your anwser @Phil , I will remove the "header", but the "body" creates the body of my POST call, the problem is that the Rest Service returns a boolean and I can't read it, just that, when I review the response I can't find it anywhere